# Is it possible to upload previous changes when using a VCS?

Tags: rubymine, rubymine-7

I'm using git as a VCS and I got several commits in a project. I'd like to upload every change made after a specific commit that is not the latest. Currently, if I want to do this, I have to upload practically every file in my project, or manually search for the modified files after a certain date. Both options are kinda tedious.

Is there an option that helps finding the modified files from a certain commit? Or possibly a combination of searching and selecting the files modified in a given range?

Comment: When you talk about uploading all files or searching for file by mod date it sounds like you may need to learn more about git, commits, sha's, history, HEAD, staging, index and such concepts.  It takes most folks (myself included) a while to understand what is going on behind the scenes.  Having such knowledge is essential in order to both answer and understand the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is my fault, but the tags of my question were wrong. I'm trying to do this in Rubymine, through its interface. I know this is possible through git, but I'd rather do this through Rubymine's interface if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git log -n 1 --name-only <revision>` to get files modified within a specific revision, or `git diff --name-only <revision_1> <revision_2>` for files that were changed between two particular revisions.

Comment: That could work, except I'd have to also extract the names of the files, and possibly group them differently if I decide to only select a few of the files found. I could make a script to do that, but that's not what I'm after. I was hoping RM could show this on its file management interface somehow, so I could later deploy them as I may wish.